# What is the best method to extract a recurring blob data and put in another table ? - SQL

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database-design, relational-database

I'm developing a new webpage in (.NET framework, if that helps) for the below scenario. Every single day, we get a cab drivers report.

```
 Date   |  Blob 
-------------------------------------------------------------
15/07   |  {"DriverName1":"100kms", "DriverName2":"10kms", "Hash":"Value"...}
16/07   |  {"DriverName1":"50kms", "DriverName3":"100kms", "Hash":"Value"}
```

Notice that the 'Blob' is the actual data received in json format - contains information about the distance covered  by a driver at that particular day.

I have written a service which reads the above table & further breaks down this and puts it into a new table like below:

```
Date  |  DriverName   | KmsDriven
```

---

```
15/07    DriverName1     100
15/07    DriverName2      10
16/07    DriverName3     100
16/07    DriverName1      50
```

By populating this, I can easily do the following queries:

1. How many drivers drove on that particular day.
2. How is 'DriverName1' did for that particular week, etc.,

My questions here are:

1. Are there anything in `.NET / SQL world` to **specifically** address this or let me know if I am reinventing the wheel here.
2. Is this the right way to use the `Blob` data ?
3. Are there any **design patterns** to adhere here to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Are there anything in .NET / SQL world to specifically address this or
>      let me know if I am reinventing the wheel here.

Well, there are JSON parsers available, for example [Newtonsoft's Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Or you can use [SQL Server's own functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql). Once you have extracted individual values from JSON, you can write them into corresponding columns (in your new table).

> 2. Is this the right way to use the Blob data?

No. It violates the principle of [atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity), and therefore the first normal form.

> 3. Are there any design patterns to adhere here to?

I'm not sure about "patterns", but I don't see why would you need a BLOB in this case.

Assuming the data is uniform (i.e. it always has the same fields), you can just declare the columns you need and write directly to them (as you already proposed).

Otherwise, you may consider using SQL Server's [XML data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-type-and-columns-sql-server), which will enable you to extract some of the sections within an XML document, or insert a new section without replacing your whole document.

Comment: Blob is needed here because the corresponding system that sends the data has no processing logic or intelligence. **Are there anything to improve the design of my second table ? It seems to hold a large data that grows exponentially with time.**

Comment: You could consider extracting driver names into a separate table and then just storing their integer IDs, but that would require slightly more complicated logic during insertion (you'd have to check for driver existence). BTW, it doesn't grow any faster than the BLOB table, so I don't see that being a problem. What kind of daily volume are we talking about?

Comment: Per day we would receive one Blob with 1000 Driver details...  meaning, for 'n' number of days I would be having 'n*1000' records in that new table..  does this mean it is an eligible candidate to move to no-sql database.

Comment: Also, pls advise how keeping 'Id' in a separate table helps here?

Comment: So a million rows in 3 years, give-or-take? A relational database should be able to deal with that just fine. ID is shorter than driver name, so it would save some space, assuming most drivers repeat.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights :)